# Trouble adding dll to .net core project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a dll written in C++ which does some heavy calculations and I need to import it into my .net core project (VS2015). (It worked fine in previous version of .net but good ol' Microsoft removed that functionality...)

I know that I need to set up a local nuget feed so I can pull the dll into the project via nuget.  But I can't seem to get the nuget commands to work (yes I downloaded nuget.exe and ran it and then restarted VS2015).  Whenever I try one of the nuget commands it just says `'nuget' is not recognized as an internal....`

I even read a post that said the NuGet.CommandList could make it so that you could run the nuget functions directly in the PM console so I tried that. No dice...

I downloaded the NuGet Package Explorer tool and that is able to create the nuget packages for me but they always result in an error when I try to import them into my project.  When I add `"YourFace": "1.0.1",` to my project.json it gives the `NU1001` error with "The dependency YourFace >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved".

Here is the xml from the package explorer tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>YourFace</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Your Face</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>My package description.</description>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

I've tried editing the xml and adding various things like a `<files>` section (thought the contents explorer on the right in the tool implies that shouldn't be necessary).  Nothing has helped.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Edit:
Sometimes I get a different error:

```
Package YourFace 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package YourFace 1.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

I read somewhere that this is because the file is directly in the lib folder and it needs to be nested in a correct framework folder but that hasn't helped either.  Also, I don't know why I sometimes get one error and sometimes the other error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'nuget' is not recognized as an internal....

That is because the nuget command is different from [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) and [PowerShell reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference). NuGet is not supported by the Package Manager Console but supported by NuGet CLI reference.

Besides, For referencing external dll in .net core you need to create you own nuget package. The NuGet docs show how to create a package from a dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package
For this you need to edit the nuspec file and add the following code in the nuspec file.

```
<package>
 <metadata>
    <id>YourFace</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Your Face</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My package description.</description>
 </metadata>

 <files>
   <file src="path\*.dll" target="lib\netCoreApp1.0"/>
 </files>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the CLI documentation did help.  I was able to create the nuget package locally and reference it in my project, `"YourFace": "1.0.0",` but I get compile errors any time I try to reference it in my code (like `using YourFace;` in a controller). the package shows up correctly in the References but I get "The type of namespace name 'YourFace' could not be found..."  Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: That because .NET Core is a subset of  .NET Framework which is allowed to be used in Windows Store Apps and your C++ dll must be targeting all of .NET Framework. So the dll written in C++  should not compatible with .net core project. If above answer resolve your issue, you can mark it which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. If not, please let me know the latest information about it. If you have another question, I recommend you post it with new question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still getting errors but I'll post a new question for those.

Comment: I created a new issue here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072613/c-dll-nuget-metadata-issue  if you have any advice I'd really appreciate it.